# ASP.NET Identity Role claims missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm logging in via Google using Duende IdentityServer, which is also configured to use ASP.NET Identity for user roles etc.

Google IdentityServer Config:

```
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.ClientId = "redacted"
                options.ClientSecret = "redacted";

            });
```

Blazor UI Auth config:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})

    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "myidentityserverurl";

            options.ClientId = "web2";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.UsePkce = true;
            options.ResponseType = "code";            
            options.Scope.Add("api1");
            options.Scope.Add("roles");
            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("roles", "role");

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        });
```

API auth config:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {        
        options.Authority = "myidentityserverurl";
        options.Audience = "api1";

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });
```

I have a Blazor UI client which can successfully login via Google, which gives me back a Cookie, an access_token and an id_token.

The access_token returned from a Google login does not have any `role` claims from ASP.NET Identity, either from within Blazor or from Postman.

If I call `/connect/userinfo` in IdentityServer after logging in via google, I get the role I'm in as expected:

```
{
    "sub": "subhere",
    "name": "myname",
    "role": "SystemAdministrator",
    "preferred_username": "uuid from google"
}
```

In the Blazor app, if I get the claims from `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims` I get my `role` claim as expected.

If I make a call to my API using the access token issued as part of the login to the UI, and get the claims like so:

```
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
    }
```

I don't have any `role` claim at all here. And likewise no `role` claim in the bearer token in Postman after logging in via Google.

Here are the claims from the API, missing my `role` claim:

```
[
  {
    "type": "iss",
    "value": "myidentityserverurl"
  },
  {
    "type": "nbf",
    "value": "1653401427"
  },
  {
    "type": "iat",
    "value": "1653401427"
  },
  {
    "type": "exp",
    "value": "1653405027"
  },
  {
    "type": "aud",
    "value": "https://myidentityserverurl/resources"
  },
  {
    "type": "scope",
    "value": "openid"
  },
  {
    "type": "scope",
    "value": "profile"
  },
  {
    "type": "scope",
    "value": "api1"
  },
  {
    "type": "scope",
    "value": "roles"
  },
  {
    "type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences",
    "value": "external"
  },
  {
    "type": "client_id",
    "value": "web2"
  },
  {
    "type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
    "value": "uuidhere"
  },
  {
    "type": "auth_time",
    "value": "1653401425"
  },
  {
    "type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider",
    "value": "Google"
  },
  {
    "type": "sid",
    "value": "A9E0A3B55D35FDAE3A7DCA0126C34E75"
  },
  {
    "type": "jti",
    "value": "43C218D3076EA595B4647CD7B369C405"
  }
]
```

I have been trying for a few days to fix and I've run out of ideas. I think I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what the actual question/problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could read the document related:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html#profile-service

and try as below:

```
public class ProfileServices : IProfileService
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
        public ProfileServices(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }
 
        public async Task<List<Claim>> GetClaimsFromUserAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim> {
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject,user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName,user.UserName)
            };
 
            var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            role.ToList().ForEach(f =>
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, f));
            });    
            
           
            return claims;
        }
 
        
        public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var subjectId = context.Subject.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId);
            context.IssuedClaims =await GetClaimsFromUserAsync(user);
        }
 
        
        public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            var subjectId = context.Subject.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId);
            context.IsActive = user != null; 
        }
    }
```

Regist it in startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
```